# KDE Plasma Discover says "Update from: Flatpak (flathub)" How?

Tags: updates, kde, plasma

Kubuntu 22.04 LTS. Linux newbie here.

When I check Updates in Discover it says "Update from Flatpak (flathub)".

What am I supposed to do here? How do I do it?

As a Linux newbie, I appreciate that modern Linux is trying to make it possible to run the system from the GUI, without the command line. But there seem to be SO MANY holes where you're forced to the command line.

And I don't mind that (I like using the command line). But a hint as to what commands might be appropriate would be helpful!

[image]

Comment: Flatpaks are not a default package type of Ubuntu system (*see https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-flavor-packaging-defaults/34061 for more details moving forward particularly* thus support for them is pure upstream meaning CLI is to be expected).  Use the `flatpak` command to upgrade.

Comment: Update All did not work. It seems flatpaks are very poorly integrated with Ubuntu.

Comment: Flatpaks are an additional feature available to users which need you to add the package (*some flavors including Kubuntu provided this for some past releases, but won't be available in the future*) PLUS add the sources to your system which the users have always needed to setup for it to work (*no change here in the future; Kubuntu didn't have this setup with no flavor providing it, so it's still manual*). It maybe you didn't setup the sources correctly; which a number of users didn't do; which is part of why the default install of `flatpak` is now not automatic for the flavors in the future.

Comment: You can integrate Flatpak with the software center in Ubuntu by installing the plugin `sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak`

Comment: @Terrance Does that also integrate with Discover in Kubuntu?

Comment: Sorry, use `sudo apt install plasma-discover-backend-flatpak` instead, and you can also `plasma-discover-backend-snap` for snaps.

Comment: Are you sure there is a problem at all? The screenshot looks like the flatpak integration of discover (plasma-discover-backend-flatpak) detected an update for a via flatpak installed theme and clicking "Update All" would update it as it is supposed to do. If you don't get an error message when trying to update from discover, I don't see any problem here and you won't have to use the command line.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this.

From another thread I got the hint that some app installed with flatpak probably pulled in the Breeze GTK theme. And Discover, despite supposedly being the central place where Kubuntu manages software, can't cope.

The fix is to remove the theme - then Discover doesn't complain that it can't update it.

First do:

```
flatpak remove --unused
```

This appears to at least list the unused flatpaks. It also complains that "`Flatpak system operation Uninstall not allowed for user`".

But you can remove them one-by-one, for example :

```
flatpak remove org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Breeze
```

Once the ones that need updating are removed, and you refresh Discover, it stops whining.

Comment: Well done for solving it, and thank you for sharing it with others.